# Possible to enforce nullable reference types?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

If a class library was written with [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) enabled, the developer may not always check for `null`, as the compiler will not give warnings/errors.

Take the following code in a library with nullable reference types enabled:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod(string s)
    {
        // don't check for null as compiler is happy
        s.ToLower();
    }
    public void MyMethod2(string? s)
    {
        // check for null as compiler is warning otherwise
        if (s != null)
        {
            this.MyMethod(s);
        }
    }
}
```

If a consumer called `Class1.MyMethod` without enabling nullable reference types, they would not get a warning when making the following call:

```cs
var c = new Class1();
c.MyMethod(null);
```

Is it possible to somehow force—or at least warn—consuming code to enable nullable reference types?

Comment: Using NRT's doesn't relieve you from having to null-check your arguments (at least on public APIs)

Comment: NRTs are only annotations, deliberately so to increase the odds of getting something that's at least usable, as opposed to perfect. If calling code isn't aware of NRTs, it'll get the same behavior as if they didn't exist at all. There is no practical way to enforce different behavior without, essentially, breaking backwards compatibility entirely, which would make the feature a whole lot less useful. Opting in voluntarily is possible with `#nullable warnings`, but you can't *make* callers respect your NRTs even just as warnings -- this is by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for good reason. If it could imagine you add a new library to your project and it forces you to update hundreds of thousands of lines of code.

As the nullability has no runtime effect, you as a library author should always test your arguments in public interface to validate invalid inputs. The library internals can safely rely on nullability if you validate inputs on public interfaces.